# How to define template function signature based on enum class parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to declare a template function such that the type of the arguments of the function depend on an enum class template parameter?

The use case is roughly the following. The application maintains a collection of entities of different classes, and mappings between those entities. The mappings are encoded as struct members as follows:

```cpp
#include<unordered_set>
using std::unordered_set;

struct Entity1;
struct Entity2;

struct Entity {
};

struct Entity1 : public Entity {
   Entity1* m_parent; // source of first mapping
   Entity2* m_owner; // source of first mapping
   unordered_set<Entity1*> m_children; // destination of first mapping
};

struct Entity2 : public Entity {
   unordered_set<Entity1*> m_elements; // destination of second mapping
};
```

To code some generic procedures on mappings, I would like to be able to identify the type of the source and destination of the mapping.

```cpp
enum class Mapping { M1, M2 };

// the following is illegal
template <Mapping r> Sig {
    typename Dom;
    typename Ran;
};

using Sig.Dom<Mapping::M1> = Entity1;
using Sig.Ran<Mapping::M1> = Entity1;
using Sig.Dom<Mapping::M2> = Entity1;
using Sig.Ran<Mapping::M2> = Entity2;
```

Here is an example of generic procedure I would like to be able to instantiate.

```cpp
template <Mapping r>
void link(Sig.Dom<r>* obj1, Sig.Ran<r>* obj2);

template<>
void link<Mapping::M1>(Entity1* obj1, Entity1* obj2) {
    if (obj1->m_parent != nullptr) {
        obj1->m_parent->m_children.erase(obj1);
    }
    obj1.m_parent = obj2;
    if (obj1->m_parent != nullptr) {
        obj1->m_parent->m_children.insert(obj1);
    }
}

template<>
void link<Mapping::M2>(Entity1* obj1, Entity2* obj2) {
    if (obj1->m_owner != nullptr) {
        obj1->m_owner->m_elements.erase(obj1);
    }
    obj1.m_owner = obj2;
    if (obj1->m_owner != nullptr) {
        obj1->m_owner->m_elements.insert(obj1);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
template <Mapping r>
struct LinkParameters
{};

template<>
struct LinkParameters<Mapping::M1>
{
    using First = Entity1*;
    using Second = Entity1*;
};
template<>
struct LinkParameters<Mapping::M2>
{
    using First = Entity1*;
    using Second = Entity2*;
};

template <Mapping r>
void link(typename LinkParameters<r>::First obj1, typename LinkParameters<r>::Second obj2)
{
    if constexpr (r == Mapping::M1) {
        if (obj1->m_parent != nullptr) {
            obj1->m_parent->m_children.erase(obj1);
        }
        obj1.m_parent = obj2;
        if (obj1->m_parent != nullptr) {
            obj1->m_parent->m_children.insert(obj1);
        }
    } else {
        if (obj1->m_owner != nullptr) {
            obj1->m_owner->m_elements.erase(obj1);
        }
        obj1.m_owner = obj2;
        if (obj1->m_owner != nullptr) {
            obj1->m_owner->m_elements.insert(obj1);
        }
    }
}
```

[Full program demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dd5zYonrf)

The idea is to have as much explicit specialisation of the trait `LinkParameters` as there are possible specialisations of `link`.

For the definition of `link()`, I decided to go with the `constexpr if` solution to demonstrate another approach. You only can decide what's the best, all are mostly compatible so experiment and choose.

As an alternative, `link` could be a callable type defined with the usual idiom (global definition + explicit specialisations). As it would be a type, it could include or nest the `LinkParameters` trait for more encapsulation. This solution is left as an exercice.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what was needed. Note that there is one line missing at the start of the code excerpt: `template <Mapping r>`.

Comment: indeed ^^ fixed